# How to join an encoder and a decoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have built the following encoder-decoder architecture, and the encoder and decoder both work fine separately:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Input, Reshape, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

WORD_TO_INDEX = {"foo": 0, "bar": 1}

MAX_QUERY_WORD_COUNT = 10
QUERY_ENCODING_SIZE = 15

# ENCODER
query_encoder_input = Input(shape=(None, len(WORD_TO_INDEX)), name="query_encoder_input")
query_encoder_output = LSTM(QUERY_ENCODING_SIZE, name="query_encoder_lstm")(query_encoder_input)
query_encoder = Model(inputs=query_encoder_input, outputs=query_encoder_output)

# DECODER
query_decoder_input = Input(shape=(QUERY_ENCODING_SIZE,), name="query_decoder_input")
query_decoder_reshape = Reshape((1, QUERY_ENCODING_SIZE), name="query_decoder_reshape")(query_decoder_input)
query_decoder_lstm = LSTM(QUERY_ENCODING_SIZE, name="query_decoder_lstm", return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
recurrent_input, state_h, state_c = query_decoder_lstm(query_decoder_reshape)
states = [state_h, state_c]
query_decoder_outputs = []
for _ in range(MAX_QUERY_WORD_COUNT):
    recurrent_input, state_h, state_c = query_decoder_lstm(recurrent_input, initial_state=states)
    query_decoder_outputs.append(recurrent_input)
    states = [state_h, state_c]
query_decoder_output = Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate(x, axis=1), name="query_decoder_concat")(query_decoder_outputs)
query_decoder = Model(inputs=query_decoder_input, outputs=query_decoder_output)
```

But when I try to join them together to create an autoencoder, I get an odd error and I don't know why.

```
# AUTOENCODER
# apply the reshape layer to the output of the encoder
query_autoencoder_output = query_decoder.layers[1](query_encoder_output)
# rebuild the autoencoder by applying each layer of the decoder to the output of the encoder
for decoder_layer in query_decoder.layers[2:]:
    # this fails and I don't know why
    query_autoencoder_output = decoder_layer(query_autoencoder_output)
# the code never gets here
query_autoencoder = Model(inputs=query_encoder_input, outputs=query_autoencoder_output)
```

This throws the error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node
> query_decoder_concat/concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT,
> Tidx=DT_INT32](query_decoder_lstm/PartitionedCall_11:1,
> query_decoder_lstm/PartitionedCall_11:2,
> query_decoder_lstm/PartitionedCall_11:3,
> query_decoder_concat/concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [?,1,15],
> [?,15], [?,15], [].

[This](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) is the template I used for my decoder. (See the "What if I don't want to use teacher forcing for training?" section.)

I relied on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800025/keras-give-input-to-intermediate-layer-and-get-final-output) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546922/keras-replacing-input-layer) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183809/connecting-keras-models-replacing-input-but-keeping-layers) (especially the last one) to figure out how to combine the models together.

**What does this error mean and how can I fix it?**

Comment: for joining the two models, why not do something like `Sequential([encoder, decoder])`?

Comment: Because I did not know that that existed! Thank you! If you add that as an answer, I will accept. (It worked for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat a model as a layer * essentially *. With an autoencoder, it'll be as straightforward as something like this:

```py
autoencoder = Sequential([encoder, decoder])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some extra flexibility you can subclass `tf.keras.Model`:

```
class AutoEncoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.encoder(inputs)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

ae = AutoEncoder(encoder, decoder)

ae.fit(...
```

Full reproducible example:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
import numpy as np

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_ix = np.where(ytrain.ravel() == 1)
test_ix = np.where(ytest.ravel() == 1)

cars_train = xtrain[train_ix]
cars_test = xtest[test_ix]

cars = np.vstack([cars_train, cars_test]).astype(np.float32)/255

X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(cars).batch(8)


class Encoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.flat = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
        self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(128)
        self.dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(32)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.flat(inputs)
        x = keras.activations.selu(self.dense1(x))
        x = keras.activations.selu(self.dense2(x))
        return x


class Decoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=[32])
        self.dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(32 * 32 * 3)
        self.reshape = keras.layers.Reshape([32, 32, 3])

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = keras.activations.selu(self.dense1(inputs))
        x = keras.activations.sigmoid(self.dense2(x))
        x = self.reshape(x)
        return x


class AutoEncoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.encoder(inputs)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x


ae = AutoEncoder(Encoder(), Decoder())

loss_object = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

reconstruction_loss = keras.metrics.Mean(name='reconstruction_loss')

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()


@tf.function
def reconstruct(inputs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        out = ae(inputs)
        loss = loss_object(inputs, out)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, ae.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, ae.trainable_variables))

    reconstruction_loss(loss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    template = 'Epoch {:2} Reconstruction Loss {:.4f}'
    for epoch in range(50):
        reconstruction_loss.reset_states()
        for input_batches in X:
            reconstruct(input_batches)
        print(template.format(epoch + 1, reconstruction_loss.result()))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 35 Reconstruction Loss 0.5794
Epoch 36 Reconstruction Loss 0.5793
Epoch 37 Reconstruction Loss 0.5792
Epoch 38 Reconstruction Loss 0.5791
Epoch 39 Reconstruction Loss 0.5790
Epoch 40 Reconstruction Loss 0.5789
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of [M Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383170/5049813), but without using `Sequential`, you can do this:

```
query_autoencoder = Model(inputs=query_encoder_input, outputs=query_decoder(query_encoder_output))
query_autoencoder.summary()
```

The summary also breaks down into more layers than M Z's answer did.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Javascript and [Tensorflow JS](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest), here is an example of how to make deeper networks.

I thought I would include this since most Javascript examples of autoencoders show only one encoding and decoding layer.

```js
function buildModel (layers)
{
    const model = tf.sequential();
    layers.forEach(layer =>
    {
        model.add(layer);
    });
    return model;
}
```

Then you can make a deeper network with more encoding and decoding layers with:

```js
//               [ encoder ]   [ decoder ]
// Model layers: 20 -> 10 -> 2 -> 10 -> 20

// Encoding Layers
const encoder = [
    tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [20], units: 10, activation: 'relu' }),
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: 'relu' })
];

// Decoding Layers
const decoder = [
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 10, activation: 'relu' }),
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 20, activation: 'relu' })
];

// Build model
const model = buildModel([...encoder, ...decoder]);

// ... Then compile and Train ...
```

After training, predictions can be made with:

```js
const predictionModel = buildModel([...encoder]);
predictionModel.predict(data);
```

Comment: This question is tagged with Python, so this answer may not be the best fit here, but maybe people will come to this for Tensorflow JS stuff as well! I think your best bet is to create your own question and tag it with the appropriate tags, self-answer, and link to this question.