# Given an existing Keras model, is there a way to fix the input batch size?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a Keras model (TensorFlow 2.0) saved in hdf5 format (.h5). I want to load this existing model and change its input shape, so it only accepts a fixed batch size.

The input batch size can be fixed with the layer `tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=..., batch_size=...)`. However, I do not want to create a new model from scratch (I want to use the already existing model). Is there a way to do this using the Python TF2 api without creating the model from scratch and without adding new layers?

Comment: This would mean you would have to call the `model.compile()` which will fail as this is a frozen model. Hence, in order to change you would have to train the model again for a different input model layer OR have your layer external to this model and convert it yourself to the required shape?

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I transform an external layer with the shape I want and "append" it to an already existing (and trained) model?

Comment: You ideally cannot. Your best bet is to simply do this transformation on your own, after all this is exactly what a NN would end up doing even if you had the capabilities to do it and then provide the resultant to the existing model. Perhaps that should help you

Comment: @IgnacioGaBo, I have found similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546922/keras-replacing-input-layer) resolved which could help you to solve this query.