# How to replace a Conv2D layer in keras with multiple sequential Conv2D layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to take a particular convolution layer of VGG 19 and trying to replace it with 3 different convolutional layers such that the first conv layer of the 3 layers will satisfy the input conditions of previous layer and the last conv layer produce exactly the same output as that of original convolution layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

model_old = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
```

I have named the VGG  model as 'model_old'.

Here is the function for a 3 Conv layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten

def multiple_conv_layer(layer_id):
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(3, kernel_size=1,input_shape=(28,28,3), strides = (1,1), \
                 padding = 'same',dilation_rate = (1,1), activation = 'relu', use_bias = False))
    model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, activation = 'relu', \
                                        use_bias = False))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=1, strides = (1,1), \
                                        padding = 'same', dilation_rate = a.dilation_rate, use_bias = False))
    return(model)
```

When I tried doing like  `model_old.layers[1] = multiple_conv_layer( 1 )` the layer was not getting replaced by the new sequential model. Any leads on how to do this?

Comment: you are doing transfer learning and also wanted to put layers inside a model already trained. not a good idea! but if you're sure, you can do it by TF functional API.

Comment: Did you tried solutions that discussed [Keras replacing input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546922/keras-replacing-input-layer) may resolve your issue?